# Select Failed in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have SSN column varbyte(100) in TableA.

It has data in hexadecimal ,
ex : 9C-B2-EE
     .
     .

when i wrote

```
 sel * from TableA where ssn='9C-B2-EE'
```

SELECT Failed: 3640: Comparing BYTE data in column SSN with other types is illegal

When I wrote

```
 sel * from TableA where ssn='9C-B2-EE'xb
```

SELECT Failed: 3775: Invalid hexadecimal constant.

When I wrote

```
 sel * from TableA where ssn='9C-B2-EE'xc
```

SELECT Failed: 3775: Invalid hexadecimal constant.

Can any one help how to use ssn in where ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a format problem in SQL Assistant

Options-> Dataformat -> uncheck Display dashes between bytes for binary data values.

Now my ssn looks like 9CB2EE

```
sel * from TableA where ssn='9CB2EE'xb
```

Works !!

Thank You .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
sel * from TableA where ssn='9C-B2-EE'xc
```

Comment: xc says SELECT Failed: 3775: Invalid hexadecimal constant.